# Link to properties file outside webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a webservice that uses Java, REST, Jersey and runs on Tomcat8. The webservice requires access to a database. Depending on where we are in the process the we may be using a testdatabase, production database or something else. Ideally we would like to be able to set which database to use without requiring a code change and recompile.

The approach we have tried is to have a properties file defining the database parameters and use an environment variable to point to the file. This has proved troublesome, first we've had a hard time defining system properties on the Tomcat server that we can read from the application, also it seems like all the files will have to be defined on the classpath, i.e already configured ahead of time and part of the codebase.

This seems like fairly common scenario, so I'm sure there is a recommended way to handle situations like this?

Comment: It sounds like you have 1 web service that is interacting with a test, prod or other database according to your post.  Why not have the web service in the appropriate env (dev, test, prod)?  It's really dangerous to have 1 web service access multiple environments IMO...could mistakenly update prod...dev web services should access dev databases, test web services test databases, etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31007851/424903 ?

Comment: I would store the properties within the application and have some [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) according to the environment. According to the profile, you pack the proper properties file within your application. To read the properties file, you could have a look at [Apache DeltaSpike Configuration Mechanism](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html). Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31361654/1426227).

Comment: If the approach mentioned above doesn't fit your needs, externalize the properties file and use JNDI to refer to the file. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33635961/1426227).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zack Macomber has a point here. Don't enable your app/service to look up its settings dynamically.

Make your build process dynamic instead.

Maven, Gradle and friends all provide simple ways to modify output depending on build parameters and or tasks/profiles.

In your code always link to the same file (name). The actual file will then be included based on your task and/or build environment. Test config for tests. Production config for production.

In many cases a complete recompilation is not necessary and will therefore be skipped (this depends on your tool, of course).

No code changes at all. Moreover the code will be dumb as hell as it does not need to know anything about context.

Especially when working on something with multiple people this approach provides the most stable long-term-solution. Customizable for those who need some special, local config and most important **transparent** for all who don't need or don't want to know about runtime environment requirements!

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar case. We have created a second web service on the same endpoint (/admin) which we call to set a few configuration parameters. We also have a DB for persisting the configuration once set. To make life easier, we also created a simple UI to set these values. The user configures the values in the UI, the UI calls the /admin web service, and the /admin service sets the configuration in memory (as properties) as well as in the DB. The main web service uses the properties as dynamic configuration.

Note: we use JWT based authorization to prevent unauthorized access to /admin. But depending upon your need you can keep it unsecure, use basic HTTP auth or go with something more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if in this particular case it is wise, but it is possible indeed to create a `.properties` file anywhere on the filesystem - and link it into your application by means of a `Resources` element.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html

> The Resources element represents all the resources available to the web application. This includes classes, JAR files, HTML, JSPs and any other files that contribute to the web application. Implementations are provided to use directories, JAR files and WARs as the source of these resources and the resources implementation may be extended to provide support for files stored in other forms such as in a database or a versioned repository.

You would need a `PreResources` element here, linking to a folder, the contents of which will be made available to the application at `/WEB-INF/classes`.

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/myapp">

    <Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">

        <!-- external res folder (contains settings.properties) -->
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"       
         base="/home/whatever/path/config/"
         webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" /> 

    </Resources>    

</Context>
```

Your application now 'sees' the files in `/home/whatever/path/config/` as if they were located at `/WEB-INF/classes`.

Typically, the `Resources` element is put inside a `Context` element. The Context element must be put in a file located at:

```
$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ROOT.xml
```

See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context